# Issues removing schema and namespace with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I'm currently trying to parse the environment of Canada's daily climate data, from an attribute centric to element centric style, such that I can import the result into an access database.

I've got it working just the way I want it, but it requires me to manually cut out

```
<climatedata **xmlns:xsd="dummylink" xsd:schemaLocation="dummylink.xsd"**>
```

in order for it to work.

I've added code into my XSLT to remove the namespace from the root element in a document, but when I do this, it ends up changing the way only 1 of my tag's transform. Meaning my station data tag no longer has it's attributes formatted into elements.

Here is the XML (**after my XSLT**), shortened to see only the first day of element data. As you can see it removed **xmlns:xsd="dummylink"** and the **xsd** prefix from schemalocation, but left **schemalocation** and now incorrectly formats **stationdata**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="EnvCanStack.xsl"?>

<climatedata schemaLocation="http://www.climate.weatheroffice.gc.ca/climateData/bulkxml/bulkschema.xsd">

<lang>ENG</lang>

<stationinformation>

<name>OSHAWA WPCP</name>
<province>ONTARIO</province>
<latitude>43.87</latitude>
<longitude>-78.83</longitude>
<elevation>83.80</elevation>
<climate_identifier>6155878</climate_identifier>
<wmo_identifier></wmo_identifier>
<tc_identifier></tc_identifier>

</stationinformation>

<stationdata day="1" month="1" year="2017">

<maxtemp>4.0</maxtemp>
<mintemp>0.0</mintemp>
<meantemp>2.0</meantemp>16.00.0<totalrain>0.0</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0.0</totalsnow>
<totalprecipitation>0.0</totalprecipitation>
<snowonground>5</snowonground>

</stationdata>

</climatedata>
```

and here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- BY DEFAULT, elements and text nodes are copied,
       and elements' attributes and contents are transformed as child nodes
       of the output element -->
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- By default, attributes are transformed to elements -->
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Certain elements have only their contents transformed -->
  <xsl:template match="dirofmaxgust | speedofmaxgust | heatdegdays | cooldegdays">
    <!-- no xsl:copy, and attribute children, if any, are ignored -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Removes specific attributes (@) to be removed. Blank template body means
        the "transformation" will ignore them or basically re print them blank -->
<xsl:template match="@description|@units|@quality"/>

<!-- Where I'm trying to remove the namespace/schemalocation -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just for a reference, here is what my XML looks like when I manually cut the namespace and don't include the code to do it for me.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="EnvCanStack.xsl"?>

<climatedata>

<lang>ENG</lang>

<stationinformation>

<name>OSHAWA WPCP</name>
<province>ONTARIO</province>
<latitude>43.87</latitude>
<longitude>-78.83</longitude>
<elevation>83.80</elevation>
<climate_identifier>6155878</climate_identifier>
<wmo_identifier>
</wmo_identifier>
<tc_identifier>
</tc_identifier>

</stationinformation>

<stationdata>

<day>1</day>
<month>1</month>
<year>2017</year>
<maxtemp>4.0</maxtemp>
<mintemp>0.0</mintemp>
<meantemp>2.0</meantemp>
<totalrain>0.0</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0.0</totalsnow>
<totalprecipitation>0.0</totalprecipitation>
<snowonground>5</snowonground>

</stationdata>

</climatedata>
```

Before you hate on how I've set it up I'm a student programmer on placement and I'm extremely new to XML/XSLT so any advice/insight/explanation as to why this is happening and what I might be able to fix it with would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting template rules with different priorities. Take a look at overview of how XSLT priority works http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#priority

Remove the following template rule it should work

```
<!-- By default, attributes are transformed to elements -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

and replace the attribute template at the end as below

```
  <xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="local-name(.)='schemaLocation'">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, reading through the link you provided me right now, however when I remove the template rule for the second half of my template to remove the namespace gives me the following error.

Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'xsd'.

Comment: I see, not having the source xml mislead. I edited the post above.

Comment: Apologies @Baski, I guess since I've been staring at it for a few days I thought the question gave enough to explain. Your edited post works perfectly! I'm able to do exactly what I wanted. Do you have a recommendation for what I should/could be using for an XML/XSLT 'converter'? Currently I'm putting my stylesheet into the xml, running the XML through a browser, and grabbing the output from the browser debugger... works just fine but I'm sure there must be another way to do it? Again, thank you for showing me the capability of the xsl:choose/when.

Comment: it depends on what you do ultimately with the transformed file. You mentioned you are importing to access database. How are you currently doing? You have multiple solutions to transform and load to a datastore. In windows platform you can use powershell to do quick transformation. See https://devio.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/command-line-xslt-processor-with-powershell/